# Getting package name of application variant in gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a gradle plugin that adds a new task for every application variant. This new task needs the package name of the application variant.

This is my current code, which stopped working with the most recent version of the android gradle plugin:

```
private String getPackageName(ApplicationVariant variant) {
    // TODO: There's probably a better way to get the package name of the variant being tested.
    String packageName = variant.generateBuildConfig.packageName

    if (variant.processManifest.packageNameOverride != null) {
        packageName = variant.processManifest.packageNameOverride
    }
    packageName
}
```

This has stopped working in the most recent version of the android plugin because of changes to the build config processing. It seemed like a hack before anyway, so I'm not surprised it stopped working. Is there a canonical way to fetch the package name?

Answer (score 6):

I use this:

```
// Return the packageName for the given buildVariant
def getPackageName(variant) {
    def suffix = variant.buildType.packageNameSuffix
    def packageName = variant.productFlavors.get(0).packageName
    if (suffix != null && !suffix.isEmpty() && suffix != "null") {
        packageName += suffix
    }
    return packageName
}
```

Comment: In Android Gradle Plugin version 0.11 (and onwards), `packageNameSuffix` has changed to `applicationIdSuffix`

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found was to define `packageName` in the project's `build.gradle` and then from the plugin do `project.android.defaultConfig.packageName`.

If the project has flavors that define their own package then the solution stated by stealthcopter would work.

However a plugin is meant to work with any project regarless whether `packageName` is defined or not in `build.gradle` so these solutions are far from ideal.

Let me know if you find something better.

Answer (score 2):

This will handle nullable `applicationIdSuffix` for you:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def applicationId = [variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId, variant.buildType.applicationIdSuffix].findAll().join()
    println applicationId 
}
```