# How do I use custom source sets in Gradle Build file with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am endeavouring to migrate an Android App from Eclipse to Android Studio. The App naturally has 3 flavour dimension something along the line of:

```
flavorDimensions("skin", "cost", "market")
productFlavors {
    skin1 {
        flavorDimension "skin"
    }
    skin2 {
        flavorDimension "skin"
    }
    free {
        flavorDimension "cost"
    }
    paid {
        flavorDimension "cost"
    }
    google {
        flavorDimension "market"
    }
    samsung {
        flavorDimension "market"
    }
    amazon {
        flavorDimension "market"
    }
```

With this I have three somewhat related problems that I cannot seem to find a clear solution to.

First issue is that the "applicationId" is dependent on 2 of the 3 dimensions, skin and cost. From the example above if I build skin1PaidGoogle I would have "com.example.skin1" if I build skin2FreeAmazon I would need "com.example.skin2_free". This is a live app so there is no opportunity to change here. How can this be achieved.

Second issue is the need for custom src/res sets. The default gives me folders for each flavour and for all combination of ALL flavours. So I get folders for "skin1", "skin2", "free", "Google" etc and I get folders for "skin1FreeGoogle" and "skin1PaidAmazon" etc. I am aware I also get build type variants. I also need folders like "skin1Free" "freeAmazon" "FreeGoogle". I only need a small subset of the myriad of possibilities here. How can these additional folders be added as appropriate to the srcSets? I am aware of the priority order which affects merging but I can manage this if I can just add the folders.

Third issue is to do with dependencies. I can have "compile" lines and I can have "freeCompile" lines but I need to also have "freeAmazonCompile" type lines.

Without these capabilities it seems to me I will either have to make many compromises and  have many duplicated srcSets so any help much appreciated.

Comment: For the question #1 take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973259/getting-package-name-of-application-variant-in-gradle-plugin

Comment: For the question #2 can you explain what do you keep in different folders?

Comment: For the question #3 what dependency do you need to specify?

Comment: With regards question 2 if for example I use in-app billing in all free varieties then when for the Google market "freeGoogle" would contain Google in-app billing code. For the Amazon market "freeAmazon" would contain Amazon in-app billing code.

Comment: With regards question 3, similar to my comment on question 2 above. For all "free" versions, depending on the market, appropriate libraries need to be included e.g. freeAmazonCompile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.1.jar')

Comment: Looks like you could include Google billing and Amazon billing in the free and paid app. I would have interfaces for billing and advertisements in main source and just different implementations in Google and Amazon codebases. I would also disable something in free or paid version based on build flag. Have you considered to have one app that becomes paid as soon as user made in app purchase?

Comment: Eugen, I could indeed do as you suggest. It would mean the apk carrying Library code that was unnecessary but that may be bearable. The main issue would be that this would add new permissions to the full versions of our existing apps which i am loath to do. Also I would still have issues with free/paid resources for each of the 'skins'. I have 8 'skins', the free versions of which have some different resources (launch icons etc) to the paid versions.